# Sphinx warning : targets for x source files that are out of date

Tags: python, python-2.7, warnings, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a Sphinx based website using Sphinx bootstrap theme. Whenever I add an RST file in it and run by typing `make html`, it always gives this warning:

```
building [html]: targets for 6 source files that are out of date
```

The build is succesful, but I want to prevent this warning appear all the time. It counts the number of RST files I add. By the way, I use :orphan: at the top of my RST files to customize the navbar of my website and don't include them on index.rst. I first thought that may be due to that, but when I also delete the orphan and add my RST files to the TOC tree, it still gives this warning. Any way to remove this warning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not really a warning; it is more of a log message. You can suppress it and other similar messages by running **sphinx-build** with the **-q** (or **-Q**) option.

See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/invocation.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-q.